# Convert dot notation json

Tags: javascript, json

ive got a json object like this:

```
{
 "c.employees": "222",
 " c.arr[0].name": "thomas",
 " c.arr[0].amount": 3,
```

}

I want to convert it to object like

```
{
 c:{
 employees:"222",
 arr:[{name:thomas,amount:3}]
 }
}
```

cant find any solution :/ The array is the problem

Comment: I'm afraid there's no short solution, you'll have to write a small parser (a dozen lines I think).

Comment: Where did that original JSON come from? Is there a valid reason it's being generated in that format or could the source be changed to produce something that's actually useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no short solution, you need to parse all keys and build the intermediate objects and arrays. As this isn't trivial, here's the code :

```
var input = {
 "c.employees": "222",
 " c.arr[0].name": "thomas",
 " c.arr[0].amount": 3,
};
var output = {};
for (var key in input) {
  var tokens = key.trim().split('.'),
      obj = output;
  for (var i=0; i<tokens.length-1; i++) {
      var m = tokens[i].match(/^(\w+)\[(\d+)\]$/); // array ?
      if (m) {
         var arr = obj[m[1]];
         if (!arr) arr = obj[m[1]] = [];
        obj = arr[m[2]] = arr[m[2]]||{};
      } else {
         obj = obj[tokens[i]] = obj[tokens[i]]||{};
      }
  }
  obj[tokens[i]] = input[key];
}
console.log(output);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/napim/1/edit) (open the console)